# Execute same script in shell

Tags: php

I have made a php script for some DB maintenance. It should only be run in *cli* mode. So when it gets executed via HTTP request it should execute itself in cli mode. I have the following code:

```
if (php_sapi_name()!="cli")
    {
        shell_exec('php -e '.__FILE__.' '.$_GET["table"].' '.$_GET["field"].' '.$_GET["sig"].' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
        return;
    }
```

The problem is that it won't run that command. Is it not possible to do such thing?

> Linux dev-mint 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It's possible if you have acces to run shell script in your server. It's a hoster server ?

Comment: I have a dedicated server. I can run the script fine from the console. But I need to invoke it from a remote application

Comment: Usually the shell access through an application is disabled. I'm pretty shure that you should request for shell access,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely forgot the fact that I didn't chmod the folder..